# update data in listview using swipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-json

I am trying to update the data using swipeRefreshLayout, but every time I swipe down to refresh it is only circling but not refreshing.

Can you please help me how to fix it.

```
package com.reader.ashishyadav271.hackernewsreader;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

    Map<Integer, String> articleURLs = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, String> articleTitles = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> articleIds = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase articlesDB;
    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.red, R.color.green, R.color.blue, R.color.yellow);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                refreshContent();
            }
            });

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("articleUrl", urls.get(position));
                i.putExtra("content", content.get(position));
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        articlesDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Articles", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        articlesDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS articles (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, articleId INTEGER, url VARCHAR, title VARCHAR, content VARCHAR)");

        updateListView();

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        try {

            task.execute("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }


    }

    private void refreshContent() {
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        titles.clear();
        updateListView();

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

    }

    public void updateListView() {

        try {

            Log.i("UI UPDATED", "DONE");

            Cursor c = articlesDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM articles", null);

            int contentIndex = c.getColumnIndex("content");
            int urlIndex = c.getColumnIndex("url");
            int titleIndex = c.getColumnIndex("title");

            c.moveToFirst();

            titles.clear();
            urls.clear();


            while (c != null) {

                titles.add(c.getString(titleIndex));
                urls.add(c.getString(urlIndex));
                content.add(c.getString(contentIndex));

                c.moveToNext();

            }



            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        }catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }


    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

            try {

                url = new URL(urls[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data != -1) {

                    char current = (char) data;

                    result += current;

                    data = reader.read();

                }

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

                articlesDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM articles");

                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

                    String articleId = jsonArray.getString(i);

                    url = new URL("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/" + articleId + ".json?print=pretty");

                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                    reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                    data = reader.read();

                    String articleInfo = "";

                    while (data != -1 ) {

                        char current = (char) data;

                        articleInfo += current;

                        data = reader.read();

                    }

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(articleInfo);

                    String articleTitle = jsonObject.getString("title");
                    String articleURL = jsonObject.getString("url");    

                    String articleContent = "";

                    /*

                    url = new URL(articleURL);

                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                    reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                    data = reader.read();

                    while (data != -1 ) {

                        char current = (char) data;

                        articleInfo += current;

                        data = reader.read();    
                    }

                    */
                    articleIds.add(Integer.valueOf(articleId));
                    articleTitles.put(Integer.valueOf(articleId), articleTitle);
                    articleURLs.put(Integer.valueOf(articleId), articleURL);

                    String sql = "INSERT INTO articles (articleId, url, title, content) VALUES (? , ? , ? , ?)";


                    SQLiteStatement statement = articlesDB.compileStatement(sql);    
                    statement.bindString(1, articleId);
                    statement.bindString(2, articleURL);
                    statement.bindString(3, articleTitle);
                    statement.bindString(4, articleContent);    
                    statement.execute();
                }

            }catch (Exception e) {    
                e.printStackTrace();    
            }    
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            refreshContent();    
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: You are not closing the cursor connection i.e one of the biggest mistake in ur coding, Try debug the code whether the table really has the data in database. Print the logs and check whether data exist or not

Comment: from where data is coming ?

Comment: from hacker news json api...

Comment: sir when i am inside the for loop it is showing the data but if I am logging the data outside the loop it is not showing plz help...

Comment: i have closed the cursor...but still nothing works...@akshay

Answer (score -1):

It look like synchronism problem. I can see you load data from DownloadTask and put all of data to database. RefreshMethod query data from database.
I assume if DownloadTask do not finish yet, database isn't updated and RefreshMethod would get nothing from database. So, It is only circling but not refreshing. 
To solve synchronism problem, the right application flow should be: Raise PullToRefresh Event -> execute DownloadTask -> Wait until DownloadTask finish, RefreshMethod query database for data.
Code looks like:

```
 mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
             DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
             try {
                task.execute("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty");

             } catch (Exception e) {

             e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
        });
```